# Not able to navigate from Non-angular page to angular page in iframe

Tags: protractor

I am trying to automate angular app with in the facebook. I am able to successfully login to facebook, but whenever i try to navigate to the angular page within the iframe, it keeps kicking me out with this error message "**Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.**"

**Spec**

it('Test', function () {

```
    browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.get(URL); //navigating to my facebook page
    browser.driver.sleep(500);

    //Login to facebook
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('email')).sendKeys(email);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('pass')).sendKeys(password);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('login')).click();
    browser.driver.sleep(500);

    //navigating to angular page withtin iframe
    browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    browser.waitForAngular();
    element(by.model('name')).click();

});
```

**Config**

exports.config = 
{
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',

```
},
specs: ['test'],

framework: 'jasmine2',

jasmineNodeOpts: {

    onComplete: null,
     isVerbose: false,
     showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
   defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000
}
```

};

Protractor version - 3.3.0
npm - 2.14.12
Node - 4.2.4 
Jasmine - 2

**Logs**

> 10:33:46.248 INFO - Executing: [switch to frame: 0])
>   10:33:46.292 INFO - Done: [switch to frame: 0]
>   10:33:46.300 INFO - Executing: [execute async script: try { return (function (rootSelector, callback) {
>     var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);
>
> try {
>   if (window.getAngularTestability) {
>   window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
>   return;
>   }
>   if (!window.angular) {
>   throw new Error('window.angular is undefined.  This could be either ' +
>     'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +
>   'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\'s ' +
>   'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');
>   }
>   if (angular.getTestability) {
>   angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(callback);
>   } else {
>   if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {
>   throw new Error('root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
>    ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
>   }
>    angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser').
>      notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
>    }
>   } catch (err) {
>   callback(err.message);
>   }
>   }).apply(this, arguments); }

**Html**

we do have ng-app in our html code with in iframe

```
<iframe id=" " class=" " frameborder="" src=" " style="" name="">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=" " lang="" ng-app="appname" xmlns=" ">
<head>
<body class=" ">
</html>
</iframe>
```

Any help will be much appreciated guys

Answer (score 0):

Is your angular app in Iframe?.

Switch to defaultContent and then try to switch to Iframe.

**browser.switchTo().defaultContent();** then

**browser.driver.switchTo().frame(0);**

Protractor could not identify your angular application, from error.